# How can I enumerate all *.exes and the details about each?

Tags: search, foreach, nsis, exe

Something like:

```
//Get all search data
$search = new search('C:\', '*.exe');
while($item = $search->next())
{
$details = $item->getDetails();
append_details('C:\files.txt', implode_details($details));
}
```

But in NSIS (http://nsis.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the FindFirst/FindNext functions to loop through everything in a particular directory.

```
FindFirst $0 $1 "c:\*.exe"
FileLoop:

StrCmp $1 "" DoneFileLoop ;Check for no files
DetailPrint $1 ;Print file name

;Code to output whatever details you wanted to a txt file here

FindNext $0 $1 ;Get the next file from the list
goto FileLoop ;Go back to the top and check for no files

DoneFileLoop:
```